No wifi adapter found At ubuntu 18.04.6 : intel corporation wireless 8265/8275
my question is related to wifi not working at my ubuntu18.04
I tried to move my SSD from my Linux laptop (Dell Latitude 7480) to a new computer of the same model due to a broken laptop screen.
The new computer did not boot with the SSD.
Returned the SSD to the original laptop and attempted to swap the motherboard.
The motherboard swap was unsuccessful.
Reassembled the laptop back to its original state with a new screen. When turning on the laptop and accessing Wi-Fi settings, it says "No Wi-Fi adapter found."Everything else is functioning as before.
Which thing I tried:-
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
OUTPUT:
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78)

Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:0150]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi

rfkill list all :
OUTPUT:
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

sudo lshw -C network
    *-network                 
   description: Network controller
   product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: 78
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
   resources: irq:130 memory:ef000000-ef001fff
   *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.6
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
   logical name: enp0s31f6
   version: 21
   serial: a4:4c:c8:0d:21:06
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
    configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.1-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
    resources: irq:127 memory:ef200000-ef21ffff
   *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 2
   bus info: usb@1:2
   logical name: enp0s20f0u2c4i2
   serial: ae:49:db:49:8e:80
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ipheth ip=172.20.10.2 link=yes multicast=yes

what I tried :
sudo cp *.ucode /lib/firmware


Questions about computer maintenance and support are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Try your luck at Ask Ubuntu.
